# Visibility of a variable across threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Given the following code, Is it guaranteed to see the latest value 4 of a ?

```
int a;
mutex mtx;
void f() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    // read(a);
    // is it guarantee it will see the value 4?
}

int main() {
    a = 4;
    thread(f);
}
```

Comment: In the first step value of global variable, a will be set and once thread it created it will be able to see the value set.

Comment: The assignment `a = 4;` is done before `thread(f);` is spawned. Hence, it's guaranteed. (AFAIK, starting a thread is a sufficient sync.) If `a` is never changed after starting the thread then the lock wouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: In your code snippet, it's guaranteed even without the mutex.

Comment: Function definition location does not efect code execution order.

Comment: why would it not? Your code would do the same even without the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed:

> 32.4.2.2 Constructors          [thread.thread.constr]
>
> Synchronization: The completion of the invocation of the constructor
> synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f.

In other words, the construction of `std::thread` itself, which occurs in the original execution thread, synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the thread function. Or, in other words: everything that happens before `std::thread` gets constructed, in the original thread, is visible in the thread function.

Comment: What if I remove the unique_lock? Is a==4 still visible?